# How to get the Running StormId based on Name in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

How to get the currently running *storm Ids* based on *name* in apache storm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the Storm UI's REST API. I am not aware of any operation exposed to get a list of topologies and their associated Storm IDs by the name, but you can use the endpoint `/api/v1/topology/summary` to get a list of all running topologies with their names and storm IDs.

Here's a link to the documentation: http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/STORM-UI-REST-API.html